# integral equation at infinity

Tags: integration, integral-equations

I have 2 types of integral equation:

Type 1:  $Z(x) = f(x) + \alpha\int_{a}^{b}Z(x-\xi)d\xi$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Type 2:  $Z(x) = f(x) + \alpha\int_{a}^{x}Z(x-\xi)d\xi$

I would like to calculate $Z(\infty)$ in each case. In the first case it is trivial, since $$Z(\infty)=f(\infty) + \alpha\int_{a}^{b}Z(\infty)d\xi = f(\infty) + \alpha Z(\infty)(b-a)$$  and hence $$Z(\infty) = \dfrac{f(\infty)}{1-\alpha(b-a)}.$$

How to to calculate $Z(\infty)$ in the second case (Type 2)? I don't know how to justify $Z(\infty)$ in the integral term of Type 2 ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not convinced it would have a simple expression in the second case since it would be dependent on the behaviour of $Z$ under integration. Also, you should probably write $\lim_{n\to\infty}Z(n)$ or $\lim Z(n)$ not $Z(\infty)$ since $\infty$ is not a number unless you're in the extended reals.

Comment: Yes that's right but in my case  $f(\infty)$  and $Z(\infty)$ are reals